# Load two or more kml files using API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

How can I load two or more kml files using API V3?

In this way it works,

new google.maps.KmlLayer(
   'http://www.example.com/kml/map.kml?&rand='+(new Date()).valueOf(), {
   preserveViewport: true,
   map: map
});

but if I want to load two or more maps, what I should do?

Comment: two or more _maps_? Or two or more _KML files_? If two or more KML files, use a different KmlLayer object for each.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [google maps api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#KmlLayer), you should try something like this:

```
var kmllist = ["path1.kml", "path2.kml", ... ];
var kmllayers = [];
for kmlurl in kmllist: 
for (var i = 0; i < kmllist.length(); i++) 
{
  var lay = new google.maps.kmllayer(opts); 
  lay.setUrl(kmllist[i]);
  lay.setMap(map);
  kmllayers.push(lay);
}
```

opts = [kmlLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#KmlLayerOptions)